# Connecting wireless router to a switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Is it possible to connect my cable modem to a 5port gigabit switch and a wireless router to said switch. 
I have tried this way already but although I get connectivity hard wired to the switch, the Wifi router (also connected to the switch) does not give out ip addresses basically wifi does not work.

My issue is that my current wifi router, which my desktop is hard wired to, is slowing my internet speed. But bypassing the router (direct from modem to PC) gets me closer to the 200Mbps that I am currently paying for. 
I don't mind the Wireless devices having slower 75Mbps but I use my desktop a lot more and would like the faster speeds.

Is my only option to buy a better Wifi router?
My current one is a older Netgear but in the settings of it there is an option to allow 300Mps which is checked. But the speeds still stay under 80Mbps.
My modem says it is capable of 375Mbps.

Comment: Most cable modems that are not routers will only hand out 1 IP address, so connecting to a switch probably won't work because either the PC or router will get a usable IP address, but not both. Best bet is get a better router.